# React-Native webview onScroll Listener

Tags: webview, react-native, listener

I've been checking on the react-native docs but there doesn't seem to be any onScroll listener for the WebView component. Is there a work-around to this? The idea is to hide UI components when webview is scrolling and show them when the user stops scrolling or scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but reviewing the docs, WebView has an `onMessage` prop that takes a function.  The WebView invokes this function using `window.postMessage`.

I believe this is the recommended way of passing info from a WebView back to the parent app.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

For `WebView` from `react-native-webview`, should use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` instead of `window.postMessage`. See [react-native-webvie#communicating-between-js-and-native](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native) for details.

Old answer:

use injectedJavaScript :

```
(function(){
    var callback=function(direction){
        window.postMessage('scroll-'+ direction)}; // here you can also use json string
        var initTop=document.body.scrollTop;
        window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
            var currTop = document.body.scrollTop;
            var dist = currTop-initTop;
            if(dist === 0)
                return;
            callback(dist>0 ? 'down' : 'up');
            initTop = currTop;
        },false)
})(window);
```

Wrap the above script into a string `jsStr`, and then:

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: YOUR_URL }}
    injectedJavaScript={jsStr}
    onMessage={(event) => {
        console.log('scroll message', event.nativeEvent.data)
        // then do something with the scroll message
    }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar approach to @sophie, but I used this for my injectedJavaScript instead:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event.target.body.scrollTop);
}, false);

true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
```

For me, the previous injectedJavaScript string did nothing